# What file is added in git

Tags: git, github

I joined co-development by git for the first time.

I tried to add one file.

`$ git add event.controller.ts`

Then I confirmed the status

`$ git status`

```
On branch event-api
Your branch is behind 'origin/develop' by 9 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   ../entities/event.entity.ts
        new file:   dto/event.dto.ts
        new file:   event.controller.spec.ts
        new file:   event.controller.ts
        new file:   event.module.ts
        new file:   event.service.spec.ts
        new file:   event.service.ts
        new file:   ../repositories/event.repository.ts

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../../.env
```

It seems that 8 files was added to stage.

Why this occured? and how can I fix it ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: It's was 9 commits ahead in the origin branch. You need to pull first.

Comment: @logbasex OP is not asking about pulling. Although they will need to do that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to fixt it? Git is wonderfull enough to give you hints :) in your return message you have:

```
(use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
```

Also, you can use `git reset` to unstage : See [git-reset docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

**Why this happened?**

I guess you added them before or name you specified was pattern matching all those files, you need to investigate that. In order to include one specific file, you need to provide path (relative to path of your repo on your machine) to a file, not only its name.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly you have to take pull from devlep to your loval. so your branch is updated with that one.then you commit and push it to origin.